# Simple image upload script which stores image in server and some details in mysql as asked by user

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

hi i want an script which allow users to upload their images as well some information as asked by me like image name url its id like this. I have found some uploading script but it is not as I required. So can anyone suggest me some script .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="uploadform" name="uploadfile" action="uploadprocess.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  ">


                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
                <input id="uploadfile" type="file"  name="uploadfile"  />  
//create more input fields as you want 
</form>
```

in uploadprocess.php

```
 $whitelist = array(".png");//create while list for all items as you want
                     foreach ($whitelist as $item)
                         {

                            if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']))
                                    {
                                        $uploaddir='uploads/';
                                        $uploadfile=mysql_prep($uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']));
                                        $access=true;
                                    }
                         }
if($access){

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) ) 
                               {
                                    $name=mysql_prep(($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']));
                                    $type=mysql_prep(($_FILES['uploadfile']['type']));

                                    $size= intval($_FILES['uploadfile']['size']);
                                 //create more data as user input
// and insert into database

                                    $query="INSERT INTO upload_file (name,type,created) VALUES ('{$name}','{$type}',NOW())";
                                    $result=mysql_query($query);


}
```

Comment: where i will put my db details

Comment: at the top of uploadprocess.php file .Connect to database and store information to database